# Insert new line in unix variable after some regex

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to Unix scripting and I am trying to write a script which should be able to append new line character and print the values inside a variable into new line,instead of same line.

Since data is dynamic and it may contain many more string rather only one,I have to add a loop and some conditions inside it to save the values in variable in new line.

Strings to be stored in variable in new line format:

```
"CA 1938" "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "CA 1937" "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "CA 1934" "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

My thinking was to write some regex comparison and use that to run the insertion of new line in this varaiable.Below is the code with which I want to achieve that operation.

```
var="CA 1938 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX CA 1937 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX CA 1934 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
for i in $var; do
    #echo $i
   p="$p"$'\n'"$i"
done
echo "$p"
```

Expected output is

```
CA 1938 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CA 1937 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CA 1934 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Actual output is

```
CA
1938
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CA
1937
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CA
1934
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

So above actual output is coming because `$i` is all the string values which are separated by whitespace. Could you please help me in getting what I am looking for. Actually this *CA(number of the task)* and *XX(task description)*.

Comment: I think your example is broken.  You define `var` using backticks then never use it.  In addition, `p` and `i` are never defined.  I also doubt just `do ... done` was intentional without a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var='CA 1938 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX CA 1937 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX CA 1934 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
var="${var// CA/$'\n'CA}"
echo "$var"
```

Output:

```
CA 1938 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CA 1937 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CA 1934 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: You hit CA instead of other expression I like it bro thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -o` you can do this:

```
var='CA 1938 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX CA 1937 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX CA 1934 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

grep -oE 'CA\s+\S+\s+\S+' <<< "$var"
CA 1938 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CA 1937 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CA 1934 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Thanks great help.Could you please explain a little about CA\s+\S+\s+\S+.

Comment: The `grep` will print each matching string on it's own line.  It's looking for the text `CA`, followed by one or more spaces `\s+`, one or more non-spaces `\S+` (your `1938`, `1937`, etc), one or more spaces, then one or more non-spaces (your `XXXXXX...`).

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Thanks so much for your comment. Yes indeed that is what the regex is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing the input correctly, `for` will break `var`
into whitespace-separated parts (based on `IFS`) so you are actually
adding a new line for each "word" in `var`, not each token.

As you suggested, I would use regular expressions with `sed -r` to properly parse it, and save it to a variable:

```bash
p=$(echo $var | sed -r 's/(CA \S+ \S+ )/\1\n/g')
```

`\S` matches any non-whitespace character, `+` matches "one or more character", so the regular expression is breaking the input into lines at every "CA" followed by two words.